# Ao importar um arquivo xml ele esta vindo em branco

Tags: php, xml

Criei esse seguinte arquivo xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<usuarios>
    <usuario>
        <nome>Andrêy Ferraz</nome>
        <idade>25</idade>
    </usuario>
    <usuario>
        <nome>Carlos Meira</nome>
        <idade>30</idade>
    </usuario>
    <usuario>
        <nome>Fernando Amarelo</nome>
        <idade>40</idade>
    </usuario>
    <usuario>
        <nome>Carlos Santos</nome>
        <idade>50</idade>
    </usuario>
    <usuario>
        <nome>Jose Santana</nome>
        <idade>78</idade>
    </usuario>
    <usuario>
        <nome>Marcus Santos</nome>
        <idade>56</idade>
    </usuario>
    <usuario>
        <nome>Jose Ferreira</nome>
        <idade>67</idade>
    </usuario>
    <usuario>
        <nome>Wallatas Silva</nome>
        <idade>78</idade>
    </usuario>
    <usuario>
        <nome>Marcus Vieira</nome>
        <idade>34</idade>
    </usuario>
</usuarios>
```

Aqui eu criei um case que permiti importar esse arquivo e identificar o seu local no meu servidor:

```
case"importar"; //importando arquivo xml
            importarUsuario ($conexao, "usuario/_usuarios.xml");
            break;
```

Aqui executo a função e tento imprimir o arquivo na tela:

```
function importarUsuario ($conexao, $arquivosXml){

    $xml = simplexml_load_file($arquivosXml);
    print_r($xml);
```

Portanto esta me retornando tudo em branco, alguém teria a gentileza de mostrar onde está o meu erro??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com os trechos de codigos mostrados não há nenhum erro. Juntando tudo em um arquivo (exceto o xml) e passando a condição certa para o switch, tudo funciona. Veja:

```
<?php
$condicao = 'importar';
$conexao = null;

switch($condicao){
    case "importar"; //importando arquivo xml
            importarUsuario ($conexao, "c.xml");
        break;
}

function importarUsuario ($conexao, $arquivosXml){
    $x = simplexml_load_file('c.xml');
    print_r($x);
}
?>
```

O código acima imprime:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [usuario] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [nome] => Andrêy Ferraz [idade] => 25 ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [nome] => Carlos Meira [idade] => 30 ) [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [nome] => Fernando Amarelo [idade] => 40 ) [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [nome] => Carlos Santos [idade] => 50 ) [4] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [nome] => Jose Santana [idade] => 78 ) [5] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [nome] => Marcus Santos [idade] => 56 ) [6] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [nome] => Jose Ferreira [idade] => 67 ) [7] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [nome] => Wallatas Silva [idade] => 78 ) [8] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [nome] => Marcus Vieira [idade] => 34 ) ) )
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, portanto eu conseguir resolver apenas de outra forma. Vou te mostrar respondendo abaixo.

Answer (score 0):

Para a solução eu fiz da seguinte forma no case:

```
case"importar"; //importando arquivo xml
            importarUsuario ($conexao);
            break;
```

E na função eu tive que fazer da seguinte forma:

```
function importarUsuario ($conexao){

    $xml = simplexml_load_file('_usuarios.xml');
    print_r($xml);
```

Dessa forma evitou de aparecer tudo em branco, sinceramente não entendi porque isso ocorreu, seria talvez devido ao fato deu esta usando a versão 7 do PHP, acho que não né?